# Crawl dynamically changed web page with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, web-crawler, htmlunit

I want to crawl web page using HtmlUnit. My purpose is:

1. Load page
2. Write something to text field
3. Press download button
4. Get new page

This is the web site:  https://9xbuddy.com/

Using browser I can write an url to text field then press download button and get download link

My code is:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://9xbuddy.com/sites/fembed");
        final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
        final HtmlInput urlInput = form.getInputByName("url");
        urlInput.click();
        urlInput.type(iframeUrl);
        final List<HtmlButton> byXPath = (List<HtmlButton>) form.getByXPath("//button[@class='orange-gradient submit_btn']");
        final HtmlPage click = byXPath.get(0).click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(15000);
```

The problem is:

When I press download button it probably send Ajax reuquest because title changed to `save` and after few seconds title changed to `Process clompleted`
. With the code below I want to wait all ajax request but what i finally got is `save` title that mean HtmlUnit didn't wait for ajax. What is my way to do it?

Comment: what's the variable 'iframeUrl''s value?